# How to add "`" as autopair paired delimiter in markdown-mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've tried adding this code to the `markdown-mode-hook`

```lisp
(push '(?` . ?`) (getf autopair-extra-pairs :everywhere))
```

The documentation of `autopair-extra-pairs` explains:

> Note that this does *not* work for single characters,
>   e.x. characters you want to behave as quotes.  See the
>   docs/source comments for more details.

Which suggests the above would not work (and it didn't).  But I was unable to
figure out what would work after browsing the code for a bit.

I've also tried to muck around with the syntax table:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?` "$" markdown-mode-syntax-table)
```

Which didn't help either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>I couldn't work this out either. However, if you're running Emacs 24, you use electric-pair-mode instead. Modifying the syntax table like this worked for me:</strike>

```lisp
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook
          #'(lambda ()
              (modify-syntax-entry ?` "\"")))
```

**Edit:** As Joao Tavora points out, this seems to work in autopair, so perhaps this is all that's needed:

I was able to get this to work by modifying the syntax table, but using 'string quote' (`"`) instead of 'paired delimiter' (`"$"`):

```lisp
(modify-syntax-entry ?` "\"" markdown-mode-syntax-table)
```

Comment: I've looked at `electric-pair-mode`.  It is not flexible enough for my needs.

Comment: This very same solution seems to work perfectly with autopair! @Luke, can you explain what didn't work?

Comment: @JoaoTavora - you're right, it does seem to do the trick in autopair. What I meant was, I tried to get autopair to work, gave up, and started looking at electric-pair-mode instead.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but as an answer to this concrete question it is misleading :-). Should I add an answer, or will you edit to contain just the `modify-syntax-entry` bit?

Comment: I've updated the answer but left the old stuff in for context.

Comment: I thought Luke meant for the solution to be applied to autopair which is what I did and it worked.  I just left the question open in case there is a more canonical way.

Comment: This *is* the canonical way. You *can* use paired delimiter, but you have to write your own handler. Search the code for `paired-delimiter` for clues. At the moment, only latex seems to use the paired-delimiter class.